# r: Plot geometry collection in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I have geometric data that I would like to plot in leaflet.  In my geometry column, one row is a geometry collection, containing a line and some points, the other row only contains points.  I know that if it was just lines/points I could use addPolylines/addMarkers.

[image]

How can I plot both of these geometries in leaflet?

My data:

```
structure(list(combination = c(1, 2), geometry = structure(list(
structure(list(structure(c(1.00223626569548, 52.8556265508789
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1.00326623395723, 
52.8573368002252), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1.00429620221897, 
52.8566371609111), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1.00527520850952, 
52.8586496729252), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1.01609106327471, 
1.01909513737114, 1.01921315456779, 1.01921315456779, 52.7752838744008, 
52.7755824285876, 52.775679782771, 52.7756862730421), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("XY", 
"GEOMETRYCOLLECTION", "sfg")), structure(c(0.867595713389035, 
1.00619833369932, 1.00794400647932, 1.01899857784703, 1.01899857784703, 
1.07326277775903, 1.07332446856619, 1.07332446856619, 1.07390650792255, 
1.07418277545098, 1.07426860613946, 1.07547291798711, 1.0765835751637, 
1.07800224108829, 1.07894637866155, 52.0181779309727, 52.8610140394857, 
52.8581400758993, 52.7756018997388, 52.7756051448803, 52.8668154271298, 
52.8611112609685, 52.8616812795274, 52.8676314804611, 52.8611630811469, 
52.8615776403463, 52.8678128235613, 52.8685576174324, 52.8612926313222, 
52.8671738019108), .Dim = c(15L, 2L), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
"sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:4326", 
wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_GEOMETRY", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 0.867595713389035, 
ymin = 52.0181779309727, xmax = 1.07894637866155, ymax = 52.8685576174324
), class = "bbox"), classes = c("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION", "MULTIPOINT"
))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = 
structure(c(combination = 2L), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to transform your sf or sp object to geojson then to use:

`addGeoJSON(args)`

That will show point with marker, polygons and lines